# Get django model correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

### I am trying to get the value of my model and get the values using a for loop but it gives me this

#### I want it to print

```
Gazou
Gazou
Gazou
Gazou
Gazou
Gazou
```

`[<Watchlist: Gazou>, <Watchlist: Gazou>, <Watchlist: Gazou>, <Watchlist: Gazou>, <Watchlist: Gazou>, <Watchlist: Gazou>, <Watchlist: Gazou>, <Watchlist: Gazou>]`

## My views.py

```
def watchlist(request):
if request.method=='POST':
    name = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
    title = request.POST['title']
    print(name)
    listing = Listing.objects.get(title=title)
    all_titles = Watchlist.objects.filter(name=name)
    print(all_titles)
    print(title)
    msg = "You already have this on your watchlist"
    a = []
    for item in all_titles: 
        a.append(item)
    print(a)
    if title in a:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
    else:
        watchlist = Watchlist.objects.create(taitle=title, name=name, title=listing)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
    
    
else:
    user = request.user
    watchlist = Watchlist.objects.filter(name=user)
    return render(request, "auctions/watchlist.html", {
            "watchlist": watchlist
    })
```

## My models.py

```
class Watchlist(models.Model):
name = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
taitle = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
title = models.ForeignKey(Listing, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.taitle}"
```

I am using django 1.11.29 and python 3.8.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for item in all_titles: 
    a.append(item.name)   #Append only name.
print(a)
```